# Adding items to a ComboBox or Gallery in VSTO addin Word

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, ms-word, vsto

I need to take a list of files from one location and put their names (like items) into the comboBox or Gallery or Dropdownlist (list is better) in the Ribbon.

But I can't understand how do I import data to a Dropdownlist. 
I have this right now:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
private void ComboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\install\CSharp");//Getting files info
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.dot*"); //Getting dot or dotm
            string str = "";
            var filtered = Files.Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)); //Getting out the hidden files
            foreach (FileInfo file in filtered)
            {
                str = file.Name;

                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\install\CSharp\tulemus.txt", $"File name is: {str}" + Environment.NewLine);  //but I want to put them in to my Combobox

          //this.comboBox1.Items.Add(("How to put filtered info here instead of a text file"));
            }
        }
```

The Visual Studio error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonDropDownItem'    TemplateCopying C:\Users****\source\repos\TemplateCopying\Ribbon1.cs   39  Active

Comment: The rule on the site is on issue / question. Could you use the [edit] link, please to reduce this to one question, not two? I take it you're using the Ribbon Designer? What should trigger loading the list of files to the list? What code have you tried?

Comment: Hey. Yes the Ribbon designer is used. I would like to have Update button next to the list(the trigger). But the old list need to be in there until Update button is pressed(so we need update button only if there will be a new file). Until now I have tried   this.comboBox1.Items.Add. And I cant find the right one in internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dropdown list, insert the `DropDown` control from Visual Studio's Tools/Office Ribbon Controls pane. Assign it a Name and a Label in the Properties Pane. For purposes of this discussion, a DropDown control named `ddList` was added to a Ribbon tab.

The next decision is, when should the list be populated?

- If the list should be static, go to the `Buttons` entry in the Properties and click it to get an interface where a static list can be typed.
- In order to populate the list when the Ribbon is created (the VSTO project is loaded) write code in the Ribbon's `Load` event
- To dynamically change the list during the VSTO project's session, run basically the same code, but when it is required (a button is clicked, for example)

**Sample code to populate a list**. Create a `RibbonDropDownItem` for each list entry. Assign the properties, then append (`Add`) the entry to the DropDown control. The code is the same, whether triggered in the `Load` event, by an event of the dropdown itself, or by a button. (Note: If the button's event code is not in the Ribbon then a reference to the Ribbon class will be required.)

```
RibbonDropDownItem ddItem1 = new RibbonDropDownItem();
ddItem1.Label = "Item added at runtime";
ddList.Items.Add(ddItem1);
```

**Background for programming controls in the Ribbon Designer**

When using the Ribbon Designer, VSTO abstracts the Office Fluent UI and provides a more "intuitive" development interface than working directly with Ribbon XML. So instead of writing callbacks, VSTO creates objects that can be used similarly to, say, Windows Forms controls.

These can be accessed through the Ribbon class, by default VSTO will create (for example): Ribbbon1.cs To generate a code stub for a control's default event, double-click the control. In order to generate a code stub for other events, switch in the Properties Pane to the Events page and double-click.

Comment: Thank you for your introduction. I ended up with this code. Now it is working: RibbonDropDownItem ddItem1 = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                ddItem1.Label = $"{str}";
                ddList.Items.Add(ddItem1);

Comment: I get COM error....

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonUI'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).